# How to get children elements

Tags: intern

I have the following html that I am trying to verify:

```
<div class="project-counts-nav-wrapper" style="">
    <ul id="project-counts" class="project-counts-nav" style="">
        <li style="">0 active projects</li>
        <li style="">0 draft projects</li>
        <li style="">
        0 archived projects (
        <a href="/projects_archived">View</a>
        )
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I get text value for each 'li' tag element?

I have the following Intern js code:

```
            .findByCssSelector('#project-counts')
            .findAllByTagName('li')
              .then(function(children){
                console.info('Show children length: ' + children.length);
                console.info('children: ' + children);
                for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
                    // how do I get text for each element
                    console.info('Show children: ' + children[i];
                }

              }).end();
```

I see the following from output:

```
Show children length: 3
children: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
Show children: [object Object]
Show children: [object Object]
Show children: [object Object]
```

I'd like to get:

```
0 active projects
0 draft projects
0 archived projects
```

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.  I added chained command getVisableText after the findAllByTagName command:

```
            .findByCssSelector('#project-counts')
            .findAllByTagName('li')
            .getVisibleText()
              .then(function(children){
                console.info('Show children length: ' + children.length);
                console.info('children: ' + children);
                for(var i=0; i < children.length; i++){
                    console.info('Show each child: ' + children[i]);
                }

              }).end();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:-

```
var liElements = document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
i;
for (i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
    console.info(liElements[i].textContent);   
}
```

The above should print just the text content as desired. Note - you would want to go ahead and put in class names on your li and get the Elements using that so that you do not pull up all the li on the page.

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPOxQa?editors=101)

Comment: Thanks for your answer / reply.  I needed this to work within the Intern / Leadfoot module.  I figured it out and will be posting the solution.